# Showing boundedness of a linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $X = C[0,1]$ i.e. the set of all continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$.

I define an operator $T: X \rightarrow X$ as

$$T(x)=vx$$ where $v$ is a fixed element of $X$.

I am trying to show that $T$ is a bounded operator.

$||T(x)|| = ||vx||$ = $sup {|(vx)(t)|:t \in [0,1]}$

$||x||= sup{|x(t)|: t\in [0,1]}$

How do I show that there exists a positive real constant $c$ such that $||Tx|| \leq c||x||$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your are using the $\sup$ norm on $X$.  Then, taking all suprema over $t \in [0,1]$,

\begin{aligned}
\lVert Tx \rVert &= \sup \lvert (vx)(t)) \rvert \\
&= \sup \lvert v(t) x(t) \rvert \\ 
&\leqslant \sup\lvert v(t) \rvert \cdot \sup\lvert x(t) \lvert \\
&= \lVert v \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert
\end{aligned}
which is what you needed with $c=\lVert v \rVert$.

Moreover if $x$ is constant you would have equality at each stage so $\lVert T \rVert = \lVert v \rVert$.

Comment: $v$ and $x$ are not necessarily real-valued.. So does that third step( of $\leq$) hold for complex-valued functions also?

Comment: Yes - think of de-Moivre to see $\lvert vx\rvert = \lvert v \rvert \cdot \lvert x \rvert $.  These terms are all real valued.  Then $\sup(\lvert v\rvert \cdot \lvert x \rvert ) \leqslant \sup \lvert v \rvert \cdot \sup \lvert x \rvert$

Comment: @Gitika The inequality involves only $|x(t)|$ and $|v(t)|$ which are real.